# How to batch rename file names by delete content between certain characters Linux

Tags: linux, shell, rename

I have many files named like this:

```
BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__1.fq.gz
BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__merged.fq.gz
BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz__2.fq.gz
BHos1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__1.fq.gz
BHos1_S1_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__merged.fq.gz
BHos1_S1_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz__2.fq.gz
BHos2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__1.fq.gz
BHos2_S2_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__merged.fq.gz
BHos2_S2_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz__2.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Da_HNVMLBCXX_L2_1.fq.gz__1.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Da_HNVMLBCXX_L2_1.fq.gz__merged.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Da_HNVMLBCXX_L2_2.fq.gz__2.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Db_HNVMLBCXX_L2_1.fq.gz__1.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Db_HNVMLBCXX_L2_1.fq.gz__merged.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Db_HNVMLBCXX_L2_2.fq.gz__2.fq.gz
ML-3_H7VFTALXX_L2_1.fq.gz__1.fq.gz
ML-3_H7VFTALXX_L2_1.fq.gz__merged.fq.gz
ML-3_H7VFTALXX_L2_2.fq.gz__2.fq.gz
T2S170523_H23HKDMXX_L1_1.fq.gz__1.fq.gz
T2S170523_H23HKDMXX_L1_1.fq.gz__merged.fq.gz
T2S170523_H23HKDMXX_L1_2.fq.gz__2.fq.gz
T4S170523_H23HKDMXX_L1_1.fq.gz__1.fq.gz
```

I want to batch rename them by deleting the content between the first '_' and the '__'. So they will be like:

```
BH_1.fq.gz
BH_merged.fq.gz
BH_2.fq.gz
BHos1_1.fq.gz
BHos1_merged.fq.gz
BHos1_2.fq.gz
BHos2_1.fq.gz
BHos2_merged.fq.gz
BHos2_2.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Da_1.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Da_merged.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Da_2.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Db_1.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Db_merged.fq.gz
ChLJ1511Db_2.fq.gz
ML-3_H7VFTALXX_1.fq.gz
ML-3_H7VFTALXX_merged.fq.gz
ML-3_H7VFTALXX_2.fq.gz
T2S170523_1.fq.gz
T2S170523_merged.fq.gz
T2S170523_2.fq.gz
T4S170523_1.fq.gz
```

How to make it? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to provide more information on what are your attempts made, and type of Unix/Linux system you are in and are you allowed to use non shell builtins for this to be a proper question.

Comment: I am using linux ubuntu. I just want to batch rename these files. I have tried `rename` and `mv`, but failed.

Comment: There is no problem in posting those failed attempts. Are you using the `rename` from the default shell or the one from the perl?

Comment: I'm using the `rename` from the default shell. I don't know how to launch `rename` in perl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Perl-based rename (available is file-rename on Mint/19). Some systems are shipping with other version of rename (rename.ul), make sure you get the right one.

```
file-rename 's/_.*__//' BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__1.fq.gz
BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__merged.fq.gz
BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R2_001.fastq.gz__2.fq.gz ...
```

You can verify rename operation without executing it (-v: verbose, -n: no action)

```
file-rename -n -v 's/_.*__//' BH_Undetermined_S0_L001_R1_001.fastq.gz__1.fq.gz ...
```

Comment: Sorry, would you please explain it with more details? How to run the perl scripts in Linux? Thank you